# How to iterate through a string and assign different colors to certain keywords for displaying text in Android?

Tags: android, string, fonts, html

I want to change the font color of certain keywords. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the text editors of programming environments where certain keywords are displayed in different colors.

For example "printf" in red,"scanf" in green,brackets in dark blue etc.

Please note that I'll be receiving the string as an extra from intent. i.e,It is not a fixed sentence......the string could contain any number of words in any combination.

All I want to do is change the font color of certain words

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why printf would need a different colour than scanf?

Comment: Hehe....just saying man.....I'll give them the same color if it makes you happy !! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through a `Spannable` to find words to color is usually a matter of `indexOf()` or similar methods on `TextUtils`.

Coloring words is a matter of applying a `ForegroundColorSpan`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search) demonstrates this, albeit with a `BackgroundColorSpan`. The key method is:

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```

Here, given the existence of a `TextView` that contains the desired text to colorize, and given a string to search for (`text`), we remove all existing `BackgroundColorSpans`, then find all occurrences of the search term and apply new `BackgroundColorSpans`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I was looking for:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String x="Hello My Name is Umang Mathur";
        tv.setText(x);
        String [] keywordspurple={"Umang","Mathur","Hello"};
        for(String y:keywordspurple)
        {
        fontcolor(y,0xFF8B008B);
        }
        String [] keywordsgreen={"Name","is"};
        for(String y:keywordsgreen)
        {
        fontcolor(y,0xffff0000);
        }
    }

 private void fontcolor(String text,int color) {
            TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
            int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);
            while (index >= 0) {
              raw.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), index, index
                  + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
              index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
            }
            prose.setText(raw);
          }
```

This code resulted in setting 3 words in puple,2 in green and the word "My" was left as it is in black.