# Using Spans to replace multiple instances

Tags: android, textview

I use the code below to change out instances of `[text]` with an image. The code I have so far replaces the first instance as needed but ignores each other occurrence. I would like to change each instance of `[text]` from the content body of a string, for example:

`Hello this is [text] a test [test] sample of input [text] string.` The text within the brackets may be different each time.

Code:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder smileyConvert(String msgBody) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(msgBody);


    if( msgBody.contains("[") && msgBody.contains("]") ){
        setStartEnd(msgBody);

        AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
        InputStream imgStream = null;
        try{
            imgStream = am.open("emotes/" + ico + ".gif");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgStream);
        smiley = sizeBitmap(smiley);
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(ctx, smiley), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        return ssb;
    }else
        return ssb;
}


 public void setStartEnd(String msgBody) {

    start = msgBody.indexOf("[");
    end = (msgBody.indexOf("]") + 1);


    return;
}
```

Any tips of advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are `start` and `end` coming from?

Comment: @CommonsWare added extra code snippet :)

Comment: Take a look at this similar situation from earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393263/how-to-iterate-through-a-string-and-assign-different-colors-to-certain-keywords/17393342#17393342

Comment: hmm also I want to span the specific strings enclosed in `[` and `]` symbols