# How to add a highlight on a word?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, textview

[image]

Hello I am trying to add a highlight to a word in a text view. I have shown a example. I basically want that pink highlight to appear on a text view word. The text view word can change, so I would also want to highlight to be dynamic.

I have tried to look into how to do this, but I could not find any lead. I am very new to XML for android. Could someone give me a lead or tips on achieving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393342/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare, could this way make it so the highlight is half covering the text like the image above. I just had a quick look at your solution and some images and it's all showing full highlighting. Thanks

Comment: No. You would need to invent your own `CharacterStyle` for that. There is no built-in `BackgroundColorButOnlyOnTheBottomHalfSpan`. :-)

Comment: Take a look at the blog post [Drawing a rounded corner background on text](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5) as a possible solution.  It describes in detail how to draw a rounded background on a custom _TextView_ but I don't see why the rounded background can't be your quarter height background/underscore/highlight with the right drawable(s).